# fetching list of teams from developer portal - time out

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Trying to export an archive for Ad Hoc distribution but getting stuck with "fetching list of teams from developer portal" that times out in a minute or so and that is it.

Cannot export.

Anybody experienced that?

Comment: I'm getting this error, any solution?

Comment: I am still getting this problem 50% of the times, but lately I found sort of a solution: I noticed that when fetching stays longer than ~5 sec it never finds my profile and it always returns time out, so I just cancel it and start export over. Sometimes it takes 3-5 restarts, but eventually it goes through fetching quickly and shows my profile. SO, DO NOT WAIT FOR IT IT WILL TIME OUT, JUST START OVER.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get this all the time, never saw it before and it started happening about a week ago and now it happens frequently.  It looks like something on apple's server causing the problem.  Attempts will go through eventually if you keep retrying.  Some of the suggestions people are posting aren't actually fixing the issue, they are just doing something random and then retrying again later and it's just luck that it worked.

You can cancel the attempt quickly as when it works it will go through in a second or two, so you don't need to wait for the timeout to try again, just cancel it and retry.

Restarting wifi might help if you are having network problems and seems to fix the issue temporarily for some people.

Hope this helps and Apple fixes it soon.

Comment: updated to xcode 7.2 seems to have fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 13):

I've been experiencing this a lot with Xcode 6.4, and OS X Yosemite.

All other applications on my MacBook can happily use the WiFi, but this particular Xcode screen often hangs on the "Fetching list of teams" dialog, before timing out.

My solution: turn WiFi off on your MacBook, then turn it back on again.

[Fetching list of teams issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337550/xcode-fetching-list-of-team-time-out-member-center-dead)

Suddenly, Xcode bursts into life again, and *is* able to get the list of teams.

(Sigh.)

**Update**

Btw, if this doesn't work, reboot your MacBook.  That also fixes the problem.

Comment: I haven't had success with restarting wifi or the computer to get around the problem but retrying eventually gets through.  I suspect the wifi restart didn't do anything and it's just the fact that you retried again later that made it look like the restart fixed it.

Comment: Nope, not true.  I have had a few cases where this error has occured, and simply turning Wifi off, then back on again, *has* fixed the issue for me straightaway.  It's a Xcode bug anyway, so who knows which side-effects are really required in each case to get around this issue !

Comment: Turning WiFi OFF then ON helped

Comment: Updated xcode to 7.2 and haven't seen the issue again.

Comment: I've seen the problem on Xcode 7.2 (7C68). I tried numerous times getting a timeout, and then toggled WiFi and then it proceeded ok.

Comment: lol !   Good to see that Apple is keeping Xcode consistantly horrible, isn't it ?  (I've just wasted half a day trying to build an OTA In-House app... each new release seems to quietly add on new requirements, and zero error reporting when you get something wrong...)

Comment: Updated Xcode to 7.2 and still see this issue. What the heck!? It works after I keep retrying a few times.

Comment: I've had this with Xcode 7.2 all day today. Very frustrating. I have tried rebooting, switching WiFi on and off, and changing networks.

Comment: I upgraded to 7.1.1 and the problem went away. But now three days later I'm getting the problem again. this time with 7.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

I think iTunes Connect is having a few issues today. I've had numerous upload issues.

Comment: Mine stopped doing it next day. Turned out our IT were messing with firewall settings and that caused it, I guess.

Comment: Is this happening today as well?

Answer (score 3):

I know this might sound weird, but deleting and creating the archive worked for me. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

It was happening for me all the day. Not 100% sure why but I removed all of apple ids associated with apple developer portal in Xcode/Preference and added again only the one I need to use to upload the app. Solved the problem. 
I believe some apple ids cause problems sometimes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, really annoying if you have many accounts...

Comment: I suspect this is the issue. But I'm working on and publishing for multiple accounts, really very time-wasting.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue today on Xcode 7.1. None of the above worked for me at all. Solved the problem by updating to Xcode 7.1.1.

Comment: I couldn't upload after restarting the Mac, I tried again and again for four days. Finally I updated to XCode 7.1.1 from XCode 7.1. Fixed immediately.

Comment: updated to XCode 7.1.1 worked once now its not working again

Comment: @BenjaminJimenez: same for me - it worked once with 7.1.1 and now it's screwed again. This feels like developer for Blackberry again (their signing server was down approximately 50% of the time).

Comment: @MusiGenesis I had multiple developer accounts in my Xcode, I fixed this by deleting all accounts and adding only the one I needed to sign the IPA

Comment: @BenjaminJimenez: yeah, I have multiple accounts going on my machine also (amazing the massive number of problems this generally causes). I finally fixed this issue just now by switching to a different wifi network (just turning wifi off and back on again didn't do anything for me). WTF Apple?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue right after I added an account to my Xcode preferences, I don't know if there's a limit on how many one can have (I had eight at that point), but once I deleted the recently added account, it worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before, and sometimes waiting or restarting xcode fixes it, but not always, in which case you can do everything from the command line.

First, create an `xcarchive`

`xcodebuild archive -project PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj -scheme SCHEMENAME -archivePath PROJECTNAME.xcarchive`

Then, export the `xcarchive`. You'll need to know the name of your provisioning profile (not the *filename*), which you can find in the Apple Development Portal.

`xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath PROJECTNAME.xcarchive -exportPath PROJECTNAME -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “PROVISIONINGPROFILENAME”`

If you need additional configuration for archiving, you can read the man page for xcodebuild

Answer (score 0):

Answering my our question because I found solution that works for me (same as Accepted Answer by CodeSmith):

I am still getting this problem 50% of the times, but lately I found sort of a solution:

I noticed that when fetching stays longer than ~5 sec it never finds my profile and it always returns time out, so I just cancel it if it is longer than 5sec and start export over. Sometimes it takes 3-5 restarts, but eventually it goes through fetching very quickly ~1-2sec and shows my profile.

SO, DO NOT WAIT FOR IT! IT WILL TIME OUT, JUST START OVER.

No need to restart XCode or Mac, just cancel export and start it over.

Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting Mac immediately helped me