# xcode fetching list of team time out, member center dead

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? It was working an hour ago, now everything is dead and the status page says all is good

Comment: Yesterday, I kept getting this error the whole day though Apple System Status were all green. But today, it is working just fine without system restart or wifi reset. I've already up-voted this question yesterday.

Answer (score 23):

try disconnecting any devices you have connected.

I just tried everything SO suggested, reboots, wifi restart, iphone hotspot, nothing helped, so I unplugged my device and suddenly xcode connected and teams were fetched.

Comment: I find it ridiculous that this worked... Xcode 7 has really been disappointingly buggy.

Comment: Maybe coincidence as the issue seems to be sporadic anyway, but this appears to have just worked

Comment: Okay, after trying to upload another binary, it stopped working again - until I plugged a device BACK IN

Comment: I unplugged everything and it work, monitors, power cord, devices. Very strange

Comment: Sounds to me like Pigeon superstition https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uPmeWiFTIw

Comment: omg, can't think that unplugging devices solves it. You save my day. Thanks @jab11

Comment: I hate that unplugging my device was what fixed this problem, but thank you so much for this piece of brilliance.

Comment: me too, if you are timeout, just change the plug/unplug state of your device, it will work

Comment: Wtf.. This is exactly why I'm hating iOS development more and more.. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Just to say, I've had this issue a few times in the past week.

I'm using Xcode 6.4 with OS X Yosemite (v10.10.2), and from time to time, it just hangs on the "Fetching list of teams" message.

Most of the time, it works fine, but then it'll start to time-out, or throw an error like this:

[image]

The solution: reboot my MacBook.  It fixes the issue every time.

It's odd.  All other applications can happily access the internet, but for just this one part of Xcode, it seems unable to fetch the data it needs, and only a reboot sorts it out.  I didn't have this issue before.

And it's hard to identify if this is an issue with Xcode 6.4 or OS X Yosemite, and Xcode demanded that I upgrade to the latest OS before it'd let me update to 6.4  (so I *could* actually debug an issue with iOS 8.2) so both updates happened on the same 1-2 days.

Bug ?  Bug ?  Did I say "bug" ?  Course not.  It's an undocumented feature.

(Sigh.)

**Five hours later**

I've just had the same issue again...

[image]

However, this time, I *turned off* WiFi on my MacBook, then turned Wifi back on again.

And the problem went away.

It (almost instantly) managed to load the list of (two) teams that I belong to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Restarting wifi connection on macbook fixed it instantly for me, after trying a dozen times beforehand.

Comment: The deactivating the wifi and turn it immediately on fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 9):

I know that is late for answer but maybe my solution could help others.

### IT ALWAYS WORKS FOR ME:

**Step 1:**
Go to Xcode --> preferences --> accounts

**Step 2:**
Select your team name and click in view details
[image]

**Step 3:**
Click in

[image]

**Final step:**
Go to Window --> Organizer and try to upload again your app :D

Comment: where's this "Download All" button??

Comment: Wow, it worked. But How does this make it done? Totally not understandable

Comment: @LKM Yes seems that is a bug. I thought that Apple fixed it in the last update of Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

i resolved this by deleting my accounts and setting them up again. none of the solutions above worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10334784)

Comment: yes, the answer is: delete the accounts and set them up again.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me by disconnecting from my WiFi then reconnecting.

Answer (score 2):

Quit xcode and simulator. Open organizer and click on Upload again. This worked for me.

I tried adding the account again and also reconnected the wifi but it did not work for me but quitting xcode did.

Comment: The other solutions didn't work for me (Xcode 8.3.3), but this one did! Perhaps because the macbook air had gone to sleep during the process, Xcode got messed up and unable to connect to the apple servers

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think it is an issue at Apples server.

I just got through once 30 minutes ago but had set the wrong build version and now I get the same error again. I think we have to wait.

Comment: They probably haven't discovered the issue yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue when i had changed my account's password.

first time, i just authorized it through new passoword. (it's not working)

and then.

1. remove all appstore accounts on xcode
2. add same account with new password.

it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep retrying, I suspect the issue is on apple's server side and retry attempts will eventually get through.

You should get the list back within a second or two, so you can cancel the attempt and retry quickly rather than wait for the timeout.

Restarting wifi seems to help some people but not others.

Check your internet connection.

Upgrade XCode, 7.2 fixed this for me.

Comment: Saw this for the first time today. For me, it is only timing out for Validate requests. The Upload button works fine.

Comment: Upgrading to xCode 7.2 fixed the issue for me, haven't seen it since upgrading.

Comment: Seems like this is a way for Apple to force updates of Xcode. I've had this same issue every time there is a new version available and I'm not updated for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I had some connection problems. 
The ethernet cable was not fully plugged in.
On wifi, make sure you have a good signal.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and I resolved it.

I got hint from @jab11

I have external storage for TimeMachine. Around a week ago TimeMachine start to fail backup my disk.

I plugged out external storage not properly When it happens.

So, try like below.

1. Plug in your external storage if you have one.
2. Check your partition's health. (In my case, I erased partition which is causing fail to backup)
3. open Xcode Organiser, then upload your binary.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I removed all accounts in XCode -> Preference -> Accounts and ADD account again, then it's working well.